# Having an issue with font family LeagueGothic. (I have installed in my lab and server)

Tags: fonts

In my lab, it is showing the font correctly, where as, In server and other system, the font is not reflecting properly. Check my link [vkacademy.in/yes1](http://vkacademy.in/yes1)

```
@font-face
{
    font-family: "League Gothic";
    src: url('font/League Gothic.otf');
}

#menu_btn a
{
    font-family: "League Gothic";
    font-size: 24px;
}
```

Comment: So what does your browser's dev tools show for the retrieval of `font/League Gothic.otf`?

Comment: Can you help me I did not find out, because I have installed the font in my lab.It is coming fine when I tested in some other system. It is not reflecting please check out at your end

Comment: open your dev tools (F12 in most browsers), find the network tab, and reload your page. Then see what it's doing for the `League Gothic` font. Is it status 200 (everything is fine, from a network perspective), 404 (URL doesn't actually resolve to anything), 500 (the server has errors in the code that serves that resource), etc.